# Form Builder with AngularJS or JQuery

Tags: jquery, templates, angularjs, plugins, webforms

I am core C++ developer and I learnt Scala and Lift recently and learning AngularJS. I need to develop an application similar to http://www.jotform.com/.

There are many chances of changing the existing features or adding new features to my application. I want to build the application with plugin architecture support according to http://www.slideshare.net/ericshepherd/building-a-javascript-module-framework-at-gilt.  How to develop the plugin architecture with AngularJS. Since I am very new to web development I am not sure whether I am going in right direction.

Kindly let me know which is the best way to develop the application? Which is more suitable(AngularJS / JQuery) for developing the application like jotform?.

Comment: Please refer this link, It can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 7):

This is the best angular for builder I've seen. so far

http://selmanh.github.io/angularjs-form-builder/#/

Answer (score 1):

That application is very conducive to Angular and you shouldn't need jQuery to accomplish it (unless it's wrapped via a directive).  I've made/been working on something along those lines in Angular, myself - a dashboard editor where you could put configurable widgets on it.

You'll want to just start reading about Angular - make sure you delve into directives - you'll probably be making at least one for each sort of form widget editor and display-er.

The drag-and-drop thing is going to be pretty tricky (I haven't implemented it yet) - I'm not aware of an excellent well-tested one for angular and manually manipulating browser events yourself will take a while.

Answer (score 1):

This may help - AngularJS drag-and-drop:

http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/